# Fabric raise error if grep results returned

Tags: django, fabric

I am using Fabric to deploy Django (of course). I want to be able to run a local command which greps a string, and if returns any results, raises an exception and halts deploy.

Something like:

```
local('grep -r -n "\s console.log" .')
```

So if I get > 0 results, I want to halt progress.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it like this:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
  local('grep -r -n "\s console.log" .')
```

This will prevent Fabric from aborting the script execution in case the call returns anything different to zero.

Comment: Actually I *want* it to abort if anything > 0 is returned.

Comment: but isn't this the default behaviour? When the command returns anything other than 0, fabric will abort the script execution